# python upload string with https post

Tags: python, python-requests

We would like to upload a string with python.
I found [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) some examples and created the following script.

```
import requests
url = 'https://URL/fileupload?FileName=file.csv'
headers = {'content-type': 'octet-stream'}
files = {'file': ('ID,Name\n1,test')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers, auth=('user', 'password'))
```

The upload is working but the output contains some unexpected lines.

```
--ec7b507f800f48ab85b7b36ef40cfc44
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file"

ID,Name
1,test
--ec7b507f800f48ab85b7b36ef40cfc44--
```

The goal is to only upload the following from `files = {'file': ('ID,Name\n1,test')}`:

```
ID,Name
1,test
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `files` parameter, `requests` creates the headers and body required to post files.
If you don't want your request formated like that you can use the `data` parameter.

```
url = 'http://httpbin.org/anything'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/octet-stream'}
files = {'file': 'ID,Name\n1,test'}
r = requests.post(url, data=files, headers=headers, auth=('user', 'password'))
print(r.request.body)
```

```
file=ID%2CName%0A1%2Ctest
```

Note that when passing a dictionary to `data` it gets url-encoded. If you want to submit your data without any encoding you can use a string.

```
url = 'http://httpbin.org/anything'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/octet-stream'}
files = 'ID,Name\n1,test'
r = requests.post(url, data=files, headers=headers, auth=('user', 'password'))
print(r.request.body)
```

```
ID,Name
1,test
```